# How do I generate a time limited key or password without storing data

Tags: .net, security, authentication, passwords, one-time-password

Here is my scenario...

1. Users client application makes a request to a web service for access.
2. Webservice responds with a "key" that is only valid for X seconds/minutes (time could be variable or at least definable in my web service)
3. Users client application uses the key immediately to make a further request.
4. Web service checks that the key is still valid and if it is proceeds with the request, otherwise responds accordingly.

I need to do this without actually storing the key in the database so I'm guessing that the hash used in generating the key (with a salt) should be based on time somehow.

I guess what I'm really asking is what is the best approach to do this.

Language: VB.Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we went with the following....

A salt known to the application
The users username
The current date/time + 5 seconds

combine the above in a specific order as a string and MD5 hash it.

We have a special URL that they can hit with the hash as a query string parameter.

We compare the hash to 5 hashes generated at the time of the request (one for the current second and one for each of the previous 4 seconds).  If the hash on the QS parameter matches one of these 5 hashes generated then we accept the request and perform the relevant actions.

We have a method on our API that returns a URL with the hash already applied.  API Clients can then send their request to the URL provided immediately.  Any requests made more than 5 seconds after the URL was retrieved are rejected.

So we have a key that is only valid for 5 seconds from the time it was generated.

This allows us to provide users the ability to "auto-login" their site from an API client.  The client requests the login url (which comes with the hash) and then immediately direct the users web browser to that URL.  The URL handles the request, checking the hash and if valid setting a login cookie and redirecting them to their admin page.

Simple, effective and, since all our API requests are over SSL, secure.

Comment: wouldn't it be susceptible to session hijacking?

Comment: How?  Anyone trying to hijack it would have to know the salt and the users normal credentials in order generate the key.  Since the web-service used to retrieve the key and the URL's on which the key is used are all covered by SSL it should be secure enough.

Comment: what is the "normal credentials" ?

Comment: The users login details.  Something like Username+PasswordHash+Salt+ExpiryTimestamp

Comment: Sorry, I might have misunderstood your question. So your App has an access to user credentials database at the time of check. Which means you are doing an usual authentication. which is OK. Normal form authentication takes just user name and password and sends over https after receiving the server checks the credential that it has. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP%2BHTML_form-based_authentication . But this form authentication is susceptible to Phishing, but which is okay as it is followed everywhere.

Comment: Not really unless the person doing the phishing knows the salt, the order in which we combine the different parts and the hash algorithm we use.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get around storing the key somewhere, the nature of a hash is that you can't get the information it was generated out of. If you want to get the information back, use an encryption algorithm instead.

Comment: This is incorrect.  If I know the salt then a hash based on a time (number of minutes since 1/1/1970) 2 minutes in the future would allow me to check for validity and give the hash a lifetime of 2 minutes.  What I am wondering is, is this the best way to accomplish this, or is there a better way that also does not involve storing the hash in the database.

Comment: You are using a stateless transfer system with HTTP. There is no way around saving the hash in some way or form, and a database is the best way for that.

Comment: @Femaref I agree that you need to store some info. But you can not use encryption alone for identity authentication. One of the solution in this case can one time password.

Answer (score 0):

we used a 3rd party tool for that.  It's called Crypkey.
Very configurable but not cheap.

Comment: Thank you but we are not creating a a product key.  Our system has both clients and resellers.  I am trying to create an API system that would allow a reseller to retrieve a key that they can then pass on a URL to be logged in as their reseller account to any of their own client's admin areas.