# Token with some short period validity

Tags: security, authentication

How do I create an authentication token or something which has a validity of 10 minutes or so. I have a api that uses `auth_token` to verify its request. Basically I want a way that encrypts my `auth_token` and that encrypted `auth_token` is sent with the request with short validity.

Comment: You probably want to create a session instead of salt. You cannot change the salt of a hashed password once created.

Comment: This api will be used by mobile apps.May be I used the term wrongly (salt). Basically I want a way that encrypts my auth_token and that encrypted auth_token is valid for some time

Comment: Take a look at [How to create a time limited hash/key?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10299771/53114)

Comment: I thought you were asking about windows tokens initially, maybe you could tag with internet and/or mobile os related tags...